# Bindings to use Cucumber with C

Tags: c, cucumber, bdd

Are their any bindings to use Cucumber with C?  Google keeps telling me about vegetables when I ask.

Comment: I don't know, but maybe we could get some lettuce and tomatoes and make a C-salad!

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Groan.  Where's my downvote button for comments.

Comment: @rampion a C code allowing Ruby code to be interpreted allowing to be re-translated to C code would make a C-salad. RichardJ.RossIII is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to make Ruby bindings to a C application, but I haven't heard of any C binding for a Ruby application. It seems quite hard to make something like that.

BTW, [cucumber docs](https://cucumber.io/docs#cucumber-implementations) lists all available ports and way to use their technology in an other langage.

There is :

- Java Virtual Machine: JRuby and Java
- .NET (Microsoft.NET and Mono):
- IronRuby and .NET, IronRuby and Mono
- Adobe Flex: FunFX, Melomel
- Python
- Erlang: cucumberl
- Web apps in any language, using web browser and/or Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I am Using Cucumber for while and I could not find any C binding. As Ruby is top of the C.you can try to convert it.
for more info goto www.cuke.info or https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/